# Progressive Enhancement with Node/Express routing + HIJAX Pattern?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, progressive-enhancement

I know I'm going to get some polarizing responses for this, but is it possible to use progressive enhancement, namely the [HIJAX](http://domscripting.com/blog/display/41/) pattern ([AJAX applied with P.E.](http://domscripting.com/presentations/xtech2006/)), with Node routing middleware like Express? Can you still use normal server POST/GET/ requests in Node/Express etc. while layering in AJAX intercepts?

(Please read the HIJAX link for specifics).

See also: https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydnfourblog/many-users-javascript-disabled-14121.html

Comment: Who cares what some guy who wrote an article about it decided to name it? It's a valid concept regardless.

Comment: @jraede save you anger for things that matters, life is not that long after all.

Comment: @jraede: That's a common misconception. Progressive enhancement is not the same thing as graceful degradation. Mobile-first design is a pillar of progressive enhancement. 

See [Mobile-first responsive web design](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/web/mobile-first-responsive-web-design/).

Answer (score 0):

So, there are 2 possible solutions to this.

1. Express contributor Doug Wilson [pointed out](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/2103#issuecomment-42510193) that (at least on paper), this is fairly trivial. You merely check for the `xhr` object on the request.
2. [PJAX](http://pjax.heroku.com/): "It's ajax with real permalinks, page titles, and a working back button that fully degrades."